# Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I want to translate a List of objects into a Map using Java 8's streams and lambdas.

This is how I would write it in Java 7 and below.

```
private Map<String, Choice> nameMap(List<Choice> choices) {
        final Map<String, Choice> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        for (final Choice choice : choices) {
            hashMap.put(choice.getName(), choice);
        }
        return hashMap;
}
```

I can accomplish this easily using Java 8 and Guava but I would like to know how to do this without Guava.

In Guava:

```
private Map<String, Choice> nameMap(List<Choice> choices) {
    return Maps.uniqueIndex(choices, new Function<Choice, String>() {

        @Override
        public String apply(final Choice input) {
            return input.getName();
        }
    });
}
```

And Guava with Java 8 lambdas.

```
private Map<String, Choice> nameMap(List<Choice> choices) {
    return Maps.uniqueIndex(choices, Choice::getName);
}
```

Answer (score 1518, accepted):

Based on [`Collectors` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) it's as simple as:

```
Map<String, Choice> result =
    choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Choice::getName,
                                              Function.identity()));
```

Comment: As a side note, even after Java 8, the JDK still can't compete in a brevity contest. The Guava alternative looks so much readable: `Maps.uniqueIndex(choices, Choice::getName)`.

Comment: Using (statically imported) `Seq` from the [JOOL](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOL) library (which I'd recommend to anyone using Java 8), you can also improve the brevity with:

`seq(choices).toMap(Choice::getName)`

Comment: Are there any benefits from using Function.identity? I mean, it -> it is shorter

Comment: @shabunc I don't know of any benefit and actually use `it -> it` myself. `Function.identity()` is used here mostly because it's used in the referenced documentation and that was all I knew about lambdas at the time of writing

Comment: @zapl, oh, actually it turns out there are reasons behind this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28032827/java-8-lambdas-function-identity-or-t-t

Comment: you can see my answer. how to convert list to map using generics and inversion of control: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51334242/2590960

Comment: Please check the answer by @Ulises if you need to consider duplicate Keys. Need to use Map<String, List<Choice>> instead of a Map<String, Choice>

Comment: hot to access  for example to Choice::getOtherObject::geName ? please

Comment: What's the performance difference between Guava and using streams?

Comment: @BogdanCalmac & @lukens: While Guava and jOOλ are nice choices, just using JDK with static imports alone does make it a lot shorter already: `.collect(toMap(Choice::getName, identity()))`.

Comment: I've run into so many issues with this implementation and do not recommend it in general. This throws an exception if it comes across duplicate keys. If you're _100 percent_ sure that's okay, use it, but this has caused me more problems than it's solved. In every case where this has thrown an exception (a couple times in production), it's been okay to overwrite the existing entry. I always just iterate now and flag this usage in code review.

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider True, there is a fairly hidden risk of getting an exception here. Not sure if I'd prefer a version that silently deletes data instead, but if you wanted, there's a 3 parameter overload for `toMap` which takes a merge function and e.g. `(a,b) -> b` would give you the overwrite behavior you mentioned. (`choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Choice::getName, Function.identity(), (a, b) -> b))` in the example)

Answer (score 366):

If your key is **NOT** guaranteed to be unique for all elements in the list, you should convert it to a `Map<String, List<Choice>>` instead of a `Map<String, Choice>`

```
Map<String, List<Choice>> result =
 choices.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Choice::getName));
```

Comment: This actually gives you Map<String, List<Choice>> which deals with the possibility of non-unique keys, but isn't what the OP requested. In Guava, Multimaps.index(choices, Choice::getName) is probably a better option if this is what you want anyhow.

Comment: or rather use Guava's Multimap<String, Choice> which comes quite handy in scenarios where same key maps to multiple values. There are various utility methods readily available in Guava to use such data structures rather than creating a Map<String, List<Choice>>

Comment: @RichardNichols why is the guava `Multimaps` method a better option? It can be an inconvenience since it doesn't return a `Map` Object.

Comment: @RichardNichols it might no be what OP requested but I was looking for exactly this and am so happy that this answer exists!

Answer (score 182):

Use `getName()` as the key and `Choice` itself as the value of the map:

```
Map<String, Choice> result =
    choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Choice::getName, c -> c));
```

Comment: Please write some description so that user can understand.

Comment: It's really too bad there isn't more details here, because I like this answer best.

Comment: It's equal to 
    
`choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(choice -> choice.getName(),choice -> choice));`

First function for key, second function for value

Comment: I know how easy it is to see and understand `c -> c` but `Function.identity()` carries more semantic information.  I usually use a static import so that i can just use `identity()`

Answer (score 36):

Most of the answers listed miss a case when the **list has duplicate items**. In that case, their answer will throw `IllegalStateException`. Refer to the below code **to handle list duplicates** as well:

```
public Map<String, Choice> convertListToMap(List<Choice> choices) {
    return choices.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Choice::getName, choice -> choice,
            (oldValue, newValue) -> newValue));
  }
```

Answer (score 32):

Here's another one in case you don't want to use Collectors.toMap()

```
Map<String, Choice> result =
   choices.stream().collect(HashMap<String, Choice>::new, 
                           (m, c) -> m.put(c.getName(), c),
                           (m, u) -> {});
```

Comment: Which is better to use then `Collectors.toMap()` or our own HashMap as you showed in above example?

Comment: This example provided an example for how to place something else in the map. I wanted a value not provided by a method call. Thanks!

Comment: The third argument function is not correct. There you should provide some function to merge two Hashmaps, something like Hashmap::putAll

Answer (score 24):

> One more option in simple way

```
Map<String,Choice> map = new HashMap<>();
choices.forEach(e->map.put(e.getName(),e));
```

Comment: There is no viable difference in using this or java 7 type.

Comment: The SO asked with Java 8 Streams.

Answer (score 23):

For example, if you want convert object fields to map:

Example object:

```
class Item{
        private String code;
        private String name;

        public Item(String code, String name) {
            this.code = code;
            this.name = name;
        }

        //getters and setters
    }
```

And operation convert List To Map:

```
List<Item> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Item("code1", "name1"));
list.add(new Item("code2", "name2"));

Map<String,String> map = list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(Item::getCode, Item::getName));
```

Answer (score 13):

If you don't mind using 3rd party libraries, AOL's [cyclops-react](https://github.com/aol/cyclops-react) lib (disclosure I am a contributor) has extensions for all [JDK Collection](https://medium.com/@johnmcclean/extending-jdk-8-collections-8ae8d43dd75e#.j5lxtrqze) types, including [List](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-RC1/com/aol/cyclops/data/collections/extensions/standard/ListX.html) and [Map](http://static.javadoc.io/com.aol.simplereact/cyclops-react/1.0.0-RC1/com/aol/cyclops/data/collections/extensions/standard/MapX.html).

```
ListX<Choices> choices;
Map<String, Choice> map = choices.toMap(c-> c.getName(),c->c);
```

Answer (score 12):

You can create a Stream of the indices using an IntStream and then convert them to a Map :

```
Map<Integer,Item> map = 
IntStream.range(0,items.size())
         .boxed()
         .collect(Collectors.toMap (i -> i, i -> items.get(i)));
```

Comment: This is not a good option because you do a get() call for every element, hence increasing the complexity of the operation ( o(n * k) if items is an hashmap).

Comment: Isn't get(i) on a hashmap O(1)?

Comment: @IvovanderVeeken the get(i) in the code snippet is on the list, not the map.

Comment: @Zaki I was talking about Nicolas' remark. I don't see the n*k complexity if items is a hashmap instead of a list.

Answer (score 11):

I was trying to do this and found that, using the answers above, when using `Functions.identity()` for the key to the Map, then I had issues with using a local method like `this::localMethodName` to actually work because of typing issues.

`Functions.identity()` actually does something to the typing in this case so the method would only work by returning `Object` and accepting a param of `Object`

To solve this, I ended up ditching `Functions.identity()` and using `s->s` instead.

So my code, in my case to list all directories inside a directory, and for each one use the name of the directory as the key to the map and then call a method with the directory name and return a collection of items, looks like:

```
Map<String, Collection<ItemType>> items = Arrays.stream(itemFilesDir.listFiles(File::isDirectory))
.map(File::getName)
.collect(Collectors.toMap(s->s, this::retrieveBrandItems));
```

Answer (score 11):

I will write how to convert list to map using **generics** and **inversion of control**. Just **universal method!**

**Maybe** we have **list of Integers** or list of **objects.** So the question is the following: what should be **key of the map?**

create interface

```
public interface KeyFinder<K, E> {
    K getKey(E e);
}
```

now using inversion of control:

```
  static <K, E> Map<K, E> listToMap(List<E> list, KeyFinder<K, E> finder) {
        return  list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> finder.getKey(e) , e -> e));
    }
```

For example, if we have objects of book , this class is to choose key for the map

```
public class BookKeyFinder implements KeyFinder<Long, Book> {
    @Override
    public Long getKey(Book e) {
        return e.getPrice()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I use this syntax

```
Map<Integer, List<Choice>> choiceMap = 
choices.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(choice -> choice.getName()));
```

Comment: `groupingBy` creates a `Map<K,List<V>>`, not a `Map<K,V>`.

Comment: Dup of ulises answer. And, `String getName();` (not Integer)

Answer (score 8):

Another possibility only present in comments yet:

```
Map<String, Choice> result =
choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getName(), c -> c)));
```

Useful if you want to use a parameter of a sub-object as Key:

```
Map<String, Choice> result =
choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(c -> c.getUser().getName(), c -> c)));
```

Answer (score 7):

It's possible to use streams to do this. To remove the need to explicitly use `Collectors`, it's possible to import `toMap` statically (as recommended by Effective Java, third edition).

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

private static Map<String, Choice> nameMap(List<Choice> choices) {
    return choices.stream().collect(toMap(Choice::getName, it -> it));
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
Map<String, Set<String>> collect = Arrays.asList(Locale.getAvailableLocales()).stream().collect(Collectors
                .toMap(l -> l.getDisplayCountry(), l -> Collections.singleton(l.getDisplayLanguage())));
```

Answer (score 5):

This can be done in 2 ways. Let person be the class we are going to use to demonstrate it.

```
public class Person {

    private String name;
    private int age;

    public String getAge() {
        return age;
    }
}
```

Let **persons** be the list of Persons to be converted to the map

1.Using Simple foreach and a Lambda Expression on the List

```
Map<Integer,List<Person>> mapPersons = new HashMap<>();
persons.forEach(p->mapPersons.put(p.getAge(),p));
```

2.Using Collectors on Stream defined on the given List.

```
 Map<Integer,List<Person>> mapPersons = 
           persons.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Person::getAge));
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is solution by [StreamEx](https://github.com/amaembo/streamex)

```
StreamEx.of(choices).toMap(Choice::getName, c -> c);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Map<String,Choice> map=list.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Choice::getName, s->s));
```

Even  serves this purpose for me,

```
Map<String,Choice> map=  list1.stream().collect(()-> new HashMap<String,Choice>(), 
            (r,s) -> r.put(s.getString(),s),(r,s) -> r.putAll(s));
```

Answer (score 3):

If every new value for the same key name has to be overridden:

```java
public Map < String, Choice > convertListToMap(List < Choice > choices) {
    return choices.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Choice::getName,
            Function.identity(),
            (oldValue, newValue) - > newValue));
}
```

If all choices have to be grouped in a list for a name:

```java
public Map < String, Choice > convertListToMap(List < Choice > choices) {
    return choices.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Choice::getName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
List<V> choices; // your list
Map<K,V> result = choices.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(choice::getKey(),choice));
//assuming class "V" has a method to get the key, this method must handle case of duplicates too and provide a unique key.
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `guava` one can use [kotlin-stdlib](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib)

```
private Map<String, Choice> nameMap(List<Choice> choices) {
    return CollectionsKt.associateBy(choices, Choice::getName);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<Integer> listA = new ArrayList<>();
    listA.add(1);
    listA.add(5);
    listA.add(3);
    listA.add(4);       


    System.out.println(listA.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x ->x, x->x)));
```

Comment: Sorry, but this does not do what the OP asked for (i.e. create a `Map<String, Choice>`)

Answer (score -3):

```
String array[] = {"ASDFASDFASDF","AA", "BBB", "CCCC", "DD", "EEDDDAD"};
    List<String> list = Arrays.asList(array);
    Map<Integer, String> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.length(), s -> s, (x, y) -> {
                System.out.println("Dublicate key" + x);
                return x;
            },()-> new TreeMap<>((s1,s2)->s2.compareTo(s1))));
    System.out.println(map);
```

Dublicate key AA

```
{12=ASDFASDFASDF, 7=EEDDDAD, 4=CCCC, 3=BBB, 2=AA}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do here ?? Did you read the question ?