# Method to convert `List<Employee>` to `Map<Integer,List<Employee>>`

Tags: java, guava

How can I convert `List<Employee>` to `Map<Integer,List<Employee>>`.

Group `List<Employee>` based on **depId** present in employee Object, **Map key is depId.**

Is there any method in java.util.* or in Google Guava to convert it with out iterating through list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v seems similar

Comment: @sashwat It's not the same - here OP wants a multimap, i.e. `Map<K, List<V>>`, not `Map<K, V>`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With Java 8+, you can use a stream and group by the id:

```
List<Employee> list = ...;
Map<Integer,List<Employee>> map = list.stream()
                                      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepId));
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use Guava and want to [use proper collection type, here `ListMultimap<Integer, Employee>`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#multimap), use [`Multimaps#index()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimaps.html#index%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29):

```
ListMultimap<Integer, Employee> m = Multimaps.index(list, Employee::getDepId);
```