# Java 8 Streams - Grouping into Single value

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am currently working with a `List<Map<String, Object>>` where I am trying to group across various keys within the map. 
This seems to work nicely using the Java 8 [`Stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html)s:

```
Map<Object, Map<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>>> collect =
   list
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
       item -> item.get("key1"),
       Collectors.groupingBy(item -> item.get("key2"))
   ));
```

As expected this give me a `Map<Object, Map<Object, List<Map<String, Object>>>>` which works well where the possible grouped results are greater than 1.

I have various examples where the grouping being done will **always** result in a single item in the lowest level list, for example.

**List of Rows**

```
{
  [reference="PersonX", firstname="Person", dob="test", lastname="x"],
  [reference="JohnBartlett", firstname="John", dob="test", lastname="Bartlett"]
}
```

**Grouped by reference**

*Currently - grouped into a list with 1 `Map<String,Object>`*

```
[PersonX, { [reference="PersonX", firstname="Person", dob="test", lastname="x"]}],
[JohnBartlett, { [reference="JohnBartlett", firstname="John", dob="test", lastname="Bartlett"]}]
```

*Preference - No List just a single `Map<String,Object>`*

```
[PersonX, [reference="PersonX", firstname="Person", dob="test", lastname="x"]],
[JohnBartlett, [reference="JohnBartlett", firstname="John", dob="test", lastname="Bartlett"]]
```

is there a way within the streams to force the output for these instances to be `Map<Object, Map<Object, Map<String, Object>>>` - so a single `Map<String,Object>` rather than a `List` of them?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If I understood correctly, then for the cases where you are **sure** that there is a single item, you should just replace:

```
 .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
   item -> item.get("key1"),
   Collectors.toMap(item -> item.get("key2"), Function.identity())
 ));
```

You can even provide a third argument as a `BinaryOperator` to merge your same entries (in case you need to)

Comment: What happens if there in fact are multiple values with the same key? I guess the value gets overwritten by later occurrences? Your answer would be even stronger with an explanation of this. It might be a decisive factor when deciding if to use this way of collecting to a map.

Comment: @Magnilex *What happens if there in fact are multiple values with the same key*, well care to provide a simple example? Generally, `toMap` works per Key basis, so as soon as you reach an "second time" same key, without a merge function, `toMap` will fail with an Exception. If you meant something else, please clarify

Comment: If I understand you correctly, that is what I meant. Take an example where you have a list of entities, collecting to a map with their id:s as key. Would the above method throw an exception if there where multiple entities with the same id?

Comment: @Magnilex yes, that would throw an Exception with some duplicate error message, unless you provide a merge Function as the third argument of `toMap`

Answer (score 6):

[`Collectors.toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function)) does exactly what you're looking to do.

```
Map<Object, Map<String, Object>> collect = maps.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(p -> p.get("reference"), Function.identity()));
```

#### Output:

```
{
  PersonX={firstname=Person, reference=PersonX, lastname=x, dob=test},
  JohnBartlett={firstname=John, reference=JohnBartlett, lastname=Bartlett, dob=test}
}
```

This will throw an `IllegalStateException` if you have a duplicate key, which is probably exactly what you want when you never expect there to be a duplicate record in your data:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Duplicate key JohnBartlett (attempted merging values {dob=test, lastname=Bartlett, reference=JohnBartlett, firstname=John} and {dob=test 2, lastname=Bartlett, reference=JohnBartlett, firstname=John})
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.duplicateKeyException(Collectors.java:133)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$uniqKeysMapAccumulator$1(Collectors.java:180)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(ReduceOps.java:169)
    at java.base/java.util.AbstractList$RandomAccessSpliterator.forEachRemaining(AbstractList.java:720)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(ReduceOps.java:913)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(ReferencePipeline.java:578)
    at so.UniqueKeyStreamExample.main(UniqueKeyStreamExample.java:22)
```