# How to flatten this list of wrapped maps into a different kind of map Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collectors

I'm having trouble figuring out how to deal with cleaning up some of my code to do this:

I have a List of a `Context` objects. Each `Context` has a `String userId` and a `Map<String, SomeObject> someObjects`.

I want to flatten this into a `Map<String, SomeObjects>` where the kep is the `userId`. To be more concrete:

```
class Context {
    String userId;
    Map<String, List<SomeObject>> // the String here is something other than userId
    // other stuff, getters/setters
}
```

Given `List<Context>`, I want to get `Map<String, List<SomeObject>` but where the String is actually the userId.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: What's the name of the `Map<String, List<SomeObject>>` variable? Does each context have a unique `userId`? Each `userId` has many `List<SomeObject>`s in its adjacent map -- is your intent to concatenate all of those lists together?

Comment: [Duplicate Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: there is more the one clean way, but it is not clear where the userId is stored and how can we get it (and the list of objects) the from the context

Comment: The userId is part of the Context - I'll edit the original question. Both are parts of the Context (the userId and the Map)

Comment: Do you just want all the values of the `Map<String, List<SomeObject>>` to be in one `List<SomeObject>` for each user? If so, do you want to keep duplicates? If not, would a `Set<SomeObject>` work?

Comment: @Bohemian - A set should be fine as well. I don't think I would want duplicates in here.
The values for Map<String ("category"), List<SomeObject>> should be combined into one List<SomeObject> mapped by the userId instead of the String "category".

Comment: @Mei, kindly have a look at my code too and let me know if it helps. I would highly appreciate your upvote :) Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a `Context` has a `String userid` and a `List<SomeObject> someObjects`:

```
Map<String, Set<SomeObject>> map = contexts.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Context::getUserid, 
       c -> c.getSomeObjects().values().stream()
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .collect(Collectors.toSet())
     ));
```

The key points here are the use of [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) to collect by `userid` and [`flatmap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Stream.html) to turn a `Stream<List<SomeObject>>` into a `Stream<SomeObject>` so you can collect them into one collection.

Comment: Wouldn't Collectors.toSet take care of distinct elements?

Comment: There's no point to using _both_ `.distinct()` and `.collect(toSet())`.

Comment: @nick quite so. I don't know what I was thinking (if at all)

Comment: @louis quite so. I don't know what I was thinking (if at all)

Answer (score 1):

Creating class Context to hold `String` and `Map` datatypes

```
class Context {
    String userId;
    Map<String, List<Integer>> map;

    public Context(String s, List<Integer> list) {
        userId = s;
        map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put(userId, list);
    }

    public void setValues(String s, List<Integer> list) {
        map.put(s, list);
    }

}
```

Now creating the Solution class which has `List<Context>`

```
public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<Integer> list;

        // Context c1
        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
        Context c1 = new Context("dev", list);

        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-1, -3));
        c1.setValues("dev2", list);

        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-6, -3));
        c1.setValues("dev3", list);

        // Context c2
        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(12, 15, 18));
        Context c2 = new Context("macy", list);

        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-12, -13));
        c2.setValues("macy2", list);

        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-8, -18));
        c2.setValues("macy3", list);

        // Context c3
        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(20, 30));
        Context c3 = new Context("bob", list);

        list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(-31, -32));
        c3.setValues("bob2", list);

        // Context List
        List<Context> contextList = new ArrayList<>();
        contextList.addAll(Arrays.asList(c1, c2, c3));

        retrieveRecords(contextList);
    }

    private static void retrieveRecords(List<Context> contextList) {
        // regular way of retrieving map values
        for (Context c : contextList) {
            System.out.println(c.map);
        }

        System.out.println();

        // Retrieving only those records which has String key as userID
        for (Context c : contextList) {
            System.out.println(c.userId + "\t=>\t" + c.map.get(c.userId));
        }
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but my main problem was "I want to flatten this into a Map<String, SomeObjects> where the key is the userId" so selectively printing out records would not solve my specific issue. 

Regardless, you will get my upvote for your different perspective!

Comment: I appreciate it!