# Convert from for each to stream in java lambda

Tags: java, lambda

I have the below expression

```
Map<String, String> institutionList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
institutionService.list().forEach(institution -> institutionList.put(institution.getCode(),institution.getName()));
```

I tried like below.

```
institutionService.list().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(‌​Institution::getCode‌​, Institution::getName));
```

[image]

[image]

But still error. how to convert this into stream() & map() with lambda?

Comment: try `institutionService.list().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Institution::getCode, Institution::getName));`. based on [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: the `forEach` is still cleaner and faster than `stream`

Comment: Hint: look up information on the characters \u200c and \u200b mentioned in the error message.

Comment: `\u200b and \u200b` is are  "zero-width-space" non printing characters . You should remove

Comment: See the red underline in your code below the "(I" at the word "Institution"?  Delete those two (actually four) characters and re-type them in.  You might also want to figure out where you copied them from, because non-printing characters are a nuisance.

Answer (score 0):

An example which is working just fine:

```
Map<String, String> p = new HashMap<String, String>();
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("2", "4", "1"));
p = values.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(String::toString, String::toString));
System.out.println(p);
```

results in

`{1=1, 2=2, 4=4}`

If we transfer it to your problem, the code might look like this:

I have the below expression

```
Map<String, String> institutionList = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>();
institutionList = institutionService.list().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(‌​Institution::getCode‌​, Institution::getName));
```

In this case, I assume that your service gives values of class `Institution`

Comment: It's throwing error at toMap(Institution::getCode,Institution::getName));

Comment: and you assume i can read your brain and know what error you are talking of right?

Comment: did you cops/paste the code? if yes type it by hand. also don't post pictures of code/error messages. this is all text and can be pasted just as that