# Java 8 List<String> into Map<String, K> where K is a new object that needs V in its constructor

Tags: java

Before Java 8 I would code it like this:

```
Map<String, K> resultMap = new HashMap<>();
for (str : stringsList) {
    resultMap.put(str, new K(str, new X(), new Y());
}
```

Is there any way for me to do it Java 8 style instead?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>]

Answer (score 4):

In theory, you can write:

```
Map<String, K> resultMap =
  stringsList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    str ->   /*key=*/ str,
    str -> /*value=*/ new K(str, new X(), new Y())
  ));
```

(using [java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap(Function, Function)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-)).

In practice, I think your current code is probably clearer.

Answer (score 1):

solving duplicate key collisions from ruakh's answer:

```
Map<String, K> resultMap = stringsList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        str -> str, 
        str -> new K(str, new X(), new Y()), 
        (oldVal, newVal) -> newVal)
);
```

Answer (score -2):

[Java 8 Interable Foreach](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html):

```
List<String> stringsList = Arrays.asList("123", "456", "789");
Map<String, K> resultMap = new HashMap<String, K>();
stringsList.forEach(item -> resultMap.put(item, new K(item, new X(), new Y())));
```