# Convert List of Strings into Map using Java-8 Streams API

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have List

```
List<String> cars = Arrays.asList("Ford", "Focus", "Toyota", "Yaris","Nissan", "Micra", "Honda", "Civic");
```

Now, can I convert this List into Map where I get ford = focus, Toyota = yaris, Nisan = Micra, Honda = Civic using Java 8 Streams API?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: @nullpointer not really, its a completely different problem (mapping elements together vs mapping elements with something else)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example on how you could do it :

```
 Map<String, String> carsMap =
            IntStream.iterate(0, i -> i + 2).limit(cars.size() / 2)
                    .boxed()
                    .collect(Collectors.toMap(i -> cars.get(i), i -> cars.get(i + 1)));
```

Basically, just iterates over every 2 elements and maps it with the next one.

Note that if the number of elements is not even, it won't take into consideration the last element.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Paul for the help. I tried my problem with solution suggested by @nullpointer. But it is way to confusing for people who has less knowledge of how lambda works. And my problem is entirely different than the similar questions asked here before. 
 
Moreover, I wasn't hoping to get answer of my question as I find moderators here extremely bossy and bully. But you saved my life. Thanks again. :)

Comment: @meticulous_guy :)