# Using stream to convert list of strings to list of maps with custom key

Tags: java, lambda, java-stream

Given list of strings like this:

```
"Y:Yes",
"N:No",
"A:Apple"
```

I have something like

```
Map updated = values.stream().map(v -> v.split(":")).collect(Collectors.toMap(v1 -> v1[0],v1->v1.length>1?v1[1]:v1[0]));
```

But this gives me map as:

```
{
"Y":"Yes",
"N":"No",
"A":"Apple"
}
```

How can I get a list of maps as such:

```
[
{
  name:"Y",  
  display:"Yes"
},
{
  name:"N",  
  display:"No"
},
{
  name:"A",  
  display:"Apple"
}
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: @erickson Hi I updated my question to be more descriptive.

Comment: @nullpointer hi, I looked at the other question, doesn't help my problem. I'd like to have a list of maps with custom keys.

Comment: @user1491987 Whats your current DS to represent the list? Please update the question with the current `List<>` and output `List<>` types and what's the error with your piece of code as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 9, you can use the new [immutable map static factory methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#immutable), as follows:

```
List<Map<String, String>> updated = values.stream()
    .map(v -> v.split(":"))
    .map(a -> Map.of("name", a[0], "display", a[1]))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

As you want to get a List, not a map, your last function call cannot be `Collectors.toMap`, needs to be `Collectors.toList`. Now, each invocation to the `map` method should generate a new Map, so something like this would do:

```
List updated = values.stream()
    .map(v -> {
        String[] parts = v.split(":");
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", parts[0]);
        map.put("display", parts[1]);
        return map;
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Some people would prefer:

```
List updated = values.stream()
    .map(v -> {
        String[] parts = v.split(":");
        return new HashMap<>() {{
            put("name", parts[0]);
            put("display", parts[1]);
        }};
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

which creates an extra helper class. Or if you can use Guava:

```
List updated = values.stream()
    .map(v -> {
        String[] parts = v.split(":");
        return ImmutableMap.of("name", parts[0], "display", parts[1]);
    )
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

BTW: In the examples I used `List`but the complete type of what you describe would be `List<Map<String, String>>`.

Comment: I am not sure, how you collect toList and end up with a Map

Comment: you meant the type of the variable! fixed, needs to be a List

Answer (score 1):

You can use following if you're still using **Java8**, if you happen to use **Java9** then have a look at [Federicos answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037358/5515060):

```
final List<Map<String,String>> updated = values.stream()
    .map(v -> v.split(":"))
    .map(arr -> {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("name", arr[0]);
        map.put("display", arr[1]);
        return map;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```