# Java 8 Streams API - List to Map - Merge keys

Tags: merge, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a list of Fruit objects where every Fruit has a `'name'` and `'desc'`. This list of Fruits will contain duplicate `'name'` with different `'desc'`. `i.e.`

```
{"apple","its red"},{"banana","its yellow"},{"apple", "its hard"}
```

Now, I want to use Java 8 Streams API to iterate over this list of Fruits and map them into a MAP such that key is 'name' and must not contain duplicates.

Output should be:

```
key - "apple", value - List of desc i.e.  {"its red","its hard"}
key - "banana", value - {"its yellow"}
```

Please guide.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Comment: @nullpointer I would say this is about `<K, V>` into `Map<K, List<V>>`

Answer (score 5):

Something like this, obviously not compiled...

```
yourFruitList.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
             Fruit::getName,
             Collectors.mapping(Fruit::getDesc, Collectors.toList())
       ))
```

Comment: @Hadi no worries