# Convert a Nested List to nested Map

Tags: java, java-8

How can I convert `List<Map<String,Object>>` to `Map<String,Map<String,Object>>` in java while keeping the key for outer map similar to inner `Map`.

For example:

The record

```
<1:{String1,Object1}, 2:{String2,Object2}, ...>
```

should be converted to

```
<{String1 :{String1, Object1}}, {String2:{String2,Object2}}, ...>.
```

Are there any Java APIs for doing this quite easily?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create a `Map` where each entry corresponds to a `Map<String,Object>` of the input `List` - the key is the "first" key of the `Map<String,Object>` (according to iteration order) and the value is the `Map<String,Object>` itself.

It assumes that each `Map<String,Object>` of the input `List` has at least one entry, and that the keys of all the input `Map`s are distinct. If these assumptions are incorrect, this code will throw an exception.

```
Map<String,Map<String,Object>> map = 
    list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(m -> m.keySet().iterator().next(),
                                  Function.identity()));
```

Comment: @nirajdighe read the Javadoc of the relevant classes and interfaces.