# List<Object> to Map<String, Map<String,List<Object>>>

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, hashmap

I have `List<Person>` where `Person` is as below.

```
class Person {

    String personId;
    LocalDate date;
    String type;

    // getters & setters

}
```

I'm trying to convert this to `List<Person>` to `Map<String, Map<LocalDate,List<Person>>>` where outer map's key is `personId` and inner map's key is `date` and I couldn't figure out how to achieve this. 
Thus far have tried something like below. Open to Java 8 solutions as well.

```
Map<String,Map<LocalDate,List<Person>>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
Map<LocalDate,List<Person>> innerMap = new HashMap<>();

for(Person p : list) {
    List<Person> innerList = new ArrayList<>();
    innerList.add(p);
    innerMap.put(p.getDate(), innerList);
    outerMap.put(p.getPersonId(), innerMap);
}
```

Comment: You should explain your trail of thought. Why is `innerList` declared inside the loop? Why `innerMap` declared outside? Why `outerMap` is declared outside as well?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a Nested List to nested Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48379078/convert-a-nested-list-to-nested-map)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Person::getPersonId,
        Collectors.groupingBy(
            Person::getDate
)));
```

Answer (score 7):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49799616/1876620) shows how to do it with streams and [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49799675/1876620) how to do it with a traditional iterative approach. Here's yet another way:

```
Map<String, Map<LocalDate, List<Person>>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
list.forEach(p -> outerMap
        .computeIfAbsent(p.getPersonId(), k -> new HashMap<>()) // returns innerMap
        .computeIfAbsent(p.getDate(), k -> new ArrayList<>())   // returns innerList
    .add(p)); // adds Person to innerList
```

This uses [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent(K,java.util.function.Function)) to create a new `innerMap` and put it in the `outerMap` if not present (the key being `personId`), and also to create a new `innerList` and put it in the `innerMap` if not present (the key being `date`). Finally, the `Person` is added to the `innerList`.

Comment: Glad to know about `Map.computeIfAbsent`. Thanks Federico!

Answer (score 3):

Your `for` loop organization should be changed in such a way that it tries getting an existing `List<Person>` from the nested map before proceeding with creation of the new list. This is a two-step process:

```
Map<String,Map<LocalDate,List<Person>>> outerMap = new HashMap<>();
for(Person p : list) {
    Map<LocalDate,List<Person>> innerMap = outerMap.get(p.getPersonId());
    if (innerMap == null) {
        innerMap = new HashMap<>();
        outerMap.put(p.getPersonId(), innerMap);
    }
    List<Person> innerList = innerMap.get(p.getDate());
    if (innerList == null) {
        innerList = new ArrayList<>();
        innerMap.put(p.getDate(), innerList);
    }
    innerList.add(p);
}
```