# Populating a Java Map that maps alphabets corresponding to their alphabetic position using streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am populating a `Map<Character, Integer>` `alphabetToNumber` which maps a letter corresponding to it alphabetical position

```
char [] alphabetArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
Map<Character, Integer> alphabetToNumber = new HashMap<>();
int counter = 1;
for(Character letter : alphabetArray) {
    alphabetToNumber.put(letter, counter);
    counter++;
}
```

The above code works but I was wondering if it can be done using Java 8 streams. Thanks.

Comment: take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v

Comment: I saw that but I am not sure how I can use the variable `counter` and update it from a stream.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
            .boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    x -> (char) x.intValue(),
                    x -> x + (1 - 'A')));
```

Or even better with too much boxing/un-boxing:

```
Map<Character, Integer> result = IntStream.rangeClosed('A', 'Z')
    .collect(
        HashMap::new,
        (map, c) -> map.put((char) c, c + (1 - 'A')),
        HashMap::putAll
    );
```

Comment: (64 being 'A' - 1)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`String.chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#chars()) to get an `IntStream`, then just rely on the fact that [`char` is really just an integer under the hood](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) and do a bit of arithmetic.

```
Map <Character, Integer> alphabetToNumber = new HashMap<>();
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".chars()
    .forEach(ch -> alphabetToNumber.put((char) ch, ch - 'A' + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `IntStream.range()` to maintain the counter and use `SimpleImmutableEntry` to maintain for each letter the two information : letter and order.

```
char[] alphabetArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();
Map<Character, Integer> alphabetToNumber =
        IntStream.range(0, alphabetArray.length)
                 .mapToObj(i -> new SimpleImmutableEntry<>(alphabetArray[i], i + 1))
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));
```

Comment: or `mapToObj(i -> new Pair<>(alphabetArray[i], i + 1))`

Answer (score 2):

```
char [] alphabetArray = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".toCharArray();

        Map<Character, Integer> data = IntStream.range(0, alphabetArray.length).boxed()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap( x -> alphabetArray[x], x -> x +1));
```

Comment: Why do you copy the `String` into a `char[]` array instead of just using `charAt(x)` on the `String` in your function?

Comment: I thought according to the question he/she is getting character array and it needs to convert into a map.

Comment: I think, the problem description “mapping alphabets corresponding to their alphabetic position” of the question makes it clear that the array is not part of the task. The OP likely used the array because `for(char c: string)` doesn’t work (though that saving of source code characters doesn’t justify the runtime costs of copying an entire string). But in your code you’re streaming over indices anyway.

Answer (score 2):

```
Map<Character, Integer> alphabetToNumber = new HashMap<>();
AtomicInteger atomicInteger = new AtomicInteger(0);
"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".chars()
    .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
    .forEach(c -> alphabetToNumber.put(c, atomicInteger.getAndIncrement()));
```