# Timer class to Map

Tags: java, list, dictionary, collections, java-stream

For example, I have some class `Person`

```
class Person {

    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String street;

    ...
}
```

Also, I have a `List<Person> personList` that contains some `Person` objects. The goal is to put these objects to `Map<Person, Timer> personMap` as keys and add `new Timer()` objects as values. So each `Person` has one `Timer()`.
I'm, trying to do next:

```
personMap = personList.stream().collect(toMap(person -> person, new Timer()));
```

But compiler says: `there is no instance(s) of type variable(s) T, U exist so that Timer conforms to Function<? super T, ? extends U>`. I've been searching here [Java 8 List into Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v/) but it doesn't work for me.

What am I missing? What's wrong with `Timer()` class?

Comment: Change `new Timer()` to `person -> new Timer()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to provide a function for **both** key and vaue to the [`Collectors::toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper, Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) where:

> keyMapper - a mapping function to produce keys
>
> valueMapper - a mapping function to produce values

You need:

```
Map<Person, Timer> personMap = personList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        person -> person,           // Function to create a key
        person -> new Timer()));    // Function to create a value
```

For better understanding, here are lambdas represented as anonymous classes using the very same Collector:

```
personList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        new Function<Person, Person>() {                    // Function to create a key
            @Override
            public Person apply(Person person) {
                return person;                              // ... return self
            }},
        new Function<Person, Timer>() {                     // Function to create a value
            @Override
            public Timer apply(Person person) {
                return new Timer();                         // ... return a new Timer
            }}
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

The second argument of `toMap` is a function (`Function<? super Person, ? extends Timer> valueMapper` in this case).

`new Timer()` is not a `Function` instance, it's a `Timer` instance (which explains the argument type mismatch error). You can fix the problem with:

```
Map<Person, Timer> map = personList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), person -> new Timer()));
```

`person -> new Timer()` is a lambda expression with the signature of the expected function.