# Java 8 how to convert List of Map to Map of List?

Tags: java, java-8

I already followed many links like : https://www.mkyong.com/java8/java-8-convert-list-to-map/ and [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v), but I did not come to know how to create `Map<Integer, List<Integer>>`

Assuming the fact that one Employee can work in many department, so I am trying to get that here

Here is my code:

```
List<Map<String, Object>> results = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(SQL, empId);

Map<Integer, List<Integer>> resultMap = new HashMap<>();

List<Integer> tempLst = new ArrayList<>();
for (Map<String, Object> map : results) {
    tempLst.add(Integer.valueOf(map.get("DEPARTMENT_ID").toString().trim()));
}
resultMap.put(empId,tempLst);
```

I tried something like below:

```
results.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(currencyId, Arrays::asList))
```

But it doesn't serve my purpose, I also tried

```
results.stream().collect(groupingBy(currencyId, mapping(Integer.valueOf(map.get("EMP_ID").toString().trim()), toList())));
```

Comment: The latter should have worked. What are the data structures in use, can you detail them better in the question? Aside: `empId` and `currencyId` are confusing, which one are you working with?

Comment: I am getting Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ";" to complete 
  Statement
 - grouping cannot be resolved to a 
  variable
 - map cannot be resolved

Comment: The `for` loop code simply does `resultMap.put(empId, results.stream()
                .map(map -> Integer.valueOf(map.get("EMP_ID").toString().trim()))
                .collect(Collectors.toList()));`

Comment: Please show example data for what your list of maps looks like and what you expect your map of lists to look like. I don't think the fact that the original list of maps comes from a database is relevant to your problem (just trying to get to the [mcve]).

Comment: @Naman - Your suggestion is retirning the List<Integer> . I simply want resultMap to be populated with right values

Comment: Does your original `for` loop work as expected? It looks a little strange that you want  a map with empId as key and a list of empId as value, or is it a list of currencyId as value that you want?

Comment: @Joakim Danielson - My original code is working as expected

Comment: Then what is wrong with keeping it as it is, this looks more like a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ in my opinion. No point in changing simple and working code just for the sake of changing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I don’t understand your problem with @Naman’s code. “populating the map” means putting the `List`. Regardless of how the code looks like. You can create the map in a single statement, `Map<Integer, List<Integer>> resultMap = Collections.singletonMap(empId, results.stream() .map(map -> Integer.valueOf(map.get("EMP_ID").toString().trim())) .collect(Collectors.toList()));`. In general, you should learn about the importance of the `parameter ->` part of lambda expressions. With that, you can fix your last code example to do the intended thing, though it’s still the same as above, putting a `List`…