# Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V> with Function

Tags: java, dictionary, java-8, set, java-stream

I tried to follow [Java 8 List into Map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v) and try to change Set to Map in one list

Instead of looping (which works)

```
for (Type t : toSet()) {
    map.put(Pair.of(t, Boolean.TRUE), this::methodAcceptingMap);
}
```

I tried with solutions as:

```
toSet().stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair.of(Function.identity(), Boolean.TRUE), 
                                 this::methodAcceptingMap));
```

But got an error converting:

```
Type mismatch: cannot convert from Pair<Function<Object,Object>,Boolean> 
to Function<? super T,? extends K>
```

My map

```
private Map<Pair<Type, Boolean>, BiConsumer<Pair<Type, Boolean>, Parameters>> map =
      new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Can you share the signature of `methodAcceptingMap`?

Comment: @ernest_k I think method is irrelevant for now, but here it's `private void methodAcceptingMap(Pair<Type, Boolean> pair, Parameters parameters)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Collectors.toMap` takes two functions, and neither of your arguments fits.

You should use:

```
Map<Pair<Type, Boolean>, BiConsumer<Pair<Type, Boolean>, Parameters>> map =
    set.stream()
       .collect(Collectors.toMap(el -> Pair.of(el, Boolean.TRUE), 
                                 el -> this::methodAcceptingMap));
```

The expression `Pair.of(t, Boolean.TRUE)` is simply not of a `Function` type. And `this::methodAcceptingMap` could fit the signature of a `BiConsumer`, but the method requires a Function. So `el -> this::methodAcceptingMap` should be used as a function that takes a stream element and returns your `BiConsumer`.

Note that the assignment context (`map =`) is important in this case. Without it, the target type of these lambda expressions will be missing and compilation will fail.

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get your example. In `for` loop you're passing the same lambda for every value. I don't see sense in that. If you really want that, you need to pass `obj -> (pair, param) -> this.methodAcceptingMap(pair, param)`:

```
toSet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
    obj -> Pair.of(obj, Boolean.TRUE), 
    obj -> (pair, param) -> this.methodAcceptingMap(pair, param)));
```

Comment: Different error `The method toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K>, Function<? super T,? extends U>) in the type Collectors is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> obj) -> {}, this::methodAcceptingMap)`

Comment: I think method is irrelevant for now, but here it's `private void methodAcceptingMap(Pair<Type, Boolean> pair, Parameters parameters)` Last solution give me different error `Lambda expression's signature does not match the signature of the functional interface method apply(? super T)`

Comment: Different error `Cannot infer type argument(s) for <R, A> collect(Collector<? super T,A,R>)`

Comment: And if you exchange `(pair, param) -> this.methodAcceptingMap(pair, param)` with method refeence, i.e: `this::methodAcceptingMap`

Comment: Same error, can you try reproduce? if needed I'll try to make a minimal example

Comment: @user7294900 ernest_k asked you to do the same thing and his works?

Comment: It wasn't exact code, now is different and before was different `toSet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(
        obj -> Pair.of(obj, Boolean.TRUE), 
        this::methodAcceptingMap));`

Comment: `       .collect(Collectors.toMap(el -> Pair.of(el, Boolean.TRUE), 
                                 el -> this::methodAcceptingMap));` . Whereas my earlier comment: "And if you exchange `(pair, param) -> this.methodAcceptingMap(pair, param)` with method refeence, i.e: `this::methodAcceptingMap`".

Comment: Still didn't work, needed to change to `el -> this::methodAcceptingMap`

Comment: There is a parameter... I asked to change `(pair, param) -> this.methodAcceptingMap(pair, param)`, not `obj -> (pair, param) -> this.methodAcceptingMap(pair, param)`

Comment: So finally `obj -> this::methodAcceptingMap`

Comment: with also making Pair returning Function as `el -> Pair.of(el, Boolean.TRUE)`

Comment: @user7294900 and what is it by me? I don't get it... Name of lambda parameter does not matter. I wrote `obj -> Pair.of(obj, Boolean.TRUE)`, you say it should be `el -> Pair.of(el, Boolean.TRUE)`, right?

Comment: This solution is actually correct. You need an assignment or method invocation context for the target types of the lambda expressions to be correctly inferred (so if you just assigned the whole expression to `map`, it'd compile).