# convert list of objects to Map<String, Object> using map/stream/collect

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

if I have something like this:

```
List<Person> fetchedPeople
```

and I want to stream through it and store it into a key-value map where key is the person ID and value is the object itself (here Person)

```
private Map<String, Person> people;
```

I tried something like this but it gives me an error:

```
PersonCache = people.stream()
      .collect(toMap(Person::getID, Person));
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: after reading the suggested answer, it turned out my question is similar to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
Map<String, Person> result = fetchedPeople.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Person::getID, e -> e));
```

I don't know if there is a way to return "the element itself" without supplying a lambda function that does that, the `e -> e` part.

Comment: [java.util.function.Function#identity](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Function.html#identity())

Comment: yeah thanks. This worked!