# Is there any way to edit list of objects with streams without creating temporary map?

Tags: java, java-stream

For example, I have some Student:

```
class Student{
private String name;
private int age;
}
```

And I have a list of Students:

```
Student st1 = new Student("Tom", 14);
Student st2 = new Student("Tom", 18);
Student st3 = new Student("Jack", 19);
```

So expected output should be like this:

```
finalList = [Student{name='Tom', age=32}, Student{name='Jack', age=19}]
```

============Worked solution=============

```
List<Student> result = rawListStudents.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Student::getName, Function.identity(), (v1, v2) -> new Student(v2.getName(), v1.getAge() + v2.getAge())))
    .values()
    .stream()
    .toList();
```

Anyway, it seems there is no opportunity to merge list without additional steps with temporary map.

Comment: What's you tried by your self?

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector#7-getting-the-sum-from-grouped-results

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java 8 List<V> into Map<K, V>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The link suggested by @Federico klez Culloca may be useful, I suggest you looking at this section https://www.baeldung.com/java-groupingby-collector#7-getting-the-sum-from-grouped-results

```java
List<Student> result = students.stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Student::getName, summingInt(Student::getAge)))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(x -> new Student(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```