# Convert in java List<POJO> to Map<String, List<Object>> where the key is a field name and value is a list of values by field

Tags: java, java-8, stream, java-stream

Convert in java `List<POJO>` to `Map<String, List<Object>>` where the key is a field name and value is a list of values by field.

```java
class Train {
    public final String source;
    public final String destination;
    public final double cost;

    public Train(String source, String destination, double cost) {
        this.source = source;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.cost = cost;
    }
}
```

For example:

```java
List<Train> trains = Arrays.asList(
    new Train("A", "B", 10.0),
    new Train("C", "D", 20.0),
    new Train("E", "F", 30.0)
);
```

It should be converted to:

```java
Map<String, List<Object>> = ...  // {source=[A, C, E], destination=[B, D, F], cost=[10.0, 20.0, 30.0]}
```

---

UPD: Not a duplicate of [#20363719](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20363719/java-8-listv-into-mapk-v) since it doesn't tell exactly how to transform data but only implies using `Collectors.toMap`

Comment: @abdoSalm, No. I've already posted the answer together with the question

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```java
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Train> trains = Arrays.asList(
                new Train("A", "B", 10.0),
                new Train("C", "D", 20.0),
                new Train("E", "F", 30.0)
        );
        Map<String, List<?>> map = Arrays.stream(Train.class.getFields())
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Field::getName, f -> trains.stream()
                        .map(x -> {
                            try {
                                return f.get(x);
                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                throw new IllegalStateException(e);
                            }
                        }).collect(Collectors.toList())));
        System.out.println(map.get("source"));          // [A, C, E]
        System.out.println(map.get("destination"));     // [B, D, F]
    }
}
```